# vimscript function give "E488 trailing characters: end if" error (NERDTree)

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am trying to function to toggle the size of my nerdtree split view.
However I am getting "E488 trailing characters: end if".

```
function! ToggleNTWidth()
    if exists("b:NERDTree")
        if g:NERDTreeWinSize == 31
            let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 50
        else
            let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 31
        end if
    end if
endfunction
```

I have tried putting in `exe` in front of statements involving computation and converting segments into string `= 50'. This did not help.

Comment: In Vimscript, `if` statements are closed with `endif`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vimscript, the closing keyword is a single word (`:endif`, also `:endfunction`, `:endwhile`, etc.)

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor. Vim would have answered this one simply by typing `:help :end` and then doing tab completion by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or pressing `<C-D>` to show all candidates (`:help c_CTRL-D`).